# flutter doctor error. GIT IS NOT IN YOUR PATH

Tags: flutter, dart

all of a sudden this error showed up. can anyone help me solve it?

**flutter doctor**
[image: flutter doctor error]

**User Environment Variables**
[image: User Environment Variables]

**System Environment Variables**
[image: System Environment Variables]

Answer (score 0):

remove all paths from environmental variables
reinstall the git so it would set its path automatically.
then add `C:\Windows\System32` to my system variable PATH.
it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong in your Git path in the last entry. If it was correctly parsed by Windows, it would separate this entry into two. You can do it yourself manually by splittling the last entry like this:

`C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe`

`C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`